# Maximum Frequency Number in an array using Hashmaps

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, hashmap

> Problem:
>
> You are given an array of integers that contain numbers in random order. Write a program to find and return the number which occurs the maximum times in the given input.
>
> If two or more elements contend for the maximum frequency, return the element which occurs in the array first.
>
> Input Format:
>
> Line 1: An Integer N i.e. size of array
>   Line 2: N integers which are elements of the array, separated by spaces
>
> Output Format:
>
> Most frequent element
>
> Constraints:
>
> 0 <= N <= 10^8
>
> Sample Input 1:
>
> ```
> 13
> 2 12 2 11 12 2 1 2 2 11 12 2 6
> ```
>
> Sample Output 1:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```

The output is incorrect, please tell what is wrong.
Here is the code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;


int highestFrequency(int *input, int n){
    unordered_map<int, int> map;
    int maxFreq = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(map.count(input[i]) > 0){
            map[input[i]]++;
            if(map[input[i]] > maxFreq){
                maxFreq = map[input[i]];
            }
        }
        map[input[i]] = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(map[input[i]] == maxFreq){
            cout << input[i];
        }
    }

    /* Don't write main().
     * the input array is already passed as function argument.
     * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
     */ 
}
```

Comment: You should return the value from the function, not print it. (You need to keep track of both the value (or an index) and the frequency.)

Comment: Is it just me or did you forget to put an `else`-statement before `map[inpuit[i]] = 1`?

Comment: Also, the whole `if(map.count(input[i]) > 0)` stuff isn't needed. `map[input[i]]++;` will just work when there's no value yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think is an efficient way to count the frequency of the elements.
    unordered_map mp;

```
// Traverse through array elements and 
// count frequencies 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    mp[arr[i]]++; 

// Traverse through map and print frequencies 
for (auto x : mp) 
    cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl; 
// found the most frequent item.
 int max_count = 0, res = -1; 
for (auto i : mp) { 
    if (max_count < i.second) { 
        res = i.first; 
        max_count = i.second; 
    } 
}
```

res is the answer

Comment: That outputs all elements though, not just the most frequent...

Comment: @melk I have made the necessary changes.

Comment: Code seems to be copied without proper attribution from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-frequencies-of-array-elements/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-frequencies-of-array-elements/.

Answer (score 1):

// java solution

```
public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){ 
    if(arr.length == 0)
        return -1;
    int maxFreq = 0;
    int number = -1;
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(arr[i]))
        {
            map.put(arr[i],map.get(arr[i])+1);
        }
        else {
            map.put(arr[i], 1);
        }
    }
    // using set data structure
    Set<Integer> keySet = map.keySet();
    for(Integer i:keySet)
    {
        if(map.get(i) > maxFreq)
        {
            number = i;
            maxFreq = map.get(i);
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

}

Comment: The question is tagged C++ and your answered doesn't provide an explanation for why OP's code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the coding ninja questions from a hashmap.
This is my code and its correct you can do a dry run you will easily understand

```
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    int maxcount=0;
    int maxf=INT32_MIN;
    unordered_map<int,int> freq;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
            freq[arr[i]]++;
            if(freq[arr[i]] > maxcount){
                maxcount=freq[arr[i]];
                maxf = arr[i];
            }
        } 
    cout<<maxf<<endl;
    
}
```

1. You can just use freq[arr[i]]++ It will automatically update the key and when the new key is found it will create and add value to it.
2. Making a count variable and updating it whenever we found greater occurrence
   and storing that key value in maxf and after that returning it;

Comment: This is not valid standard C++ and also doesn't explain why OP's code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with C++ but I think the reason you code does not work is- you are checking for a max value of occurrence while iterating over the Map. Now in case there are 2 values that have same frequency the value which occurs at the end will be stored as the final answer as you are using equality operator without having any reference to the value which had max frequency. Which means that you always have your values of map compared to the same max frequency value.
(like map[1] == 2 or map[2] == 2 || map[3]==2)

According to me, You should keep a reference to your element as well as the last max frequency. Then at the end, iterate over the array to check for the max occurred value and return it instead of printing.

Here is my code in JAVA for your reference-`

```
public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm=new HashMap<>();

    for (int j : arr) {
        int val = hm.getOrDefault(j, 0) + 1;
        hm.put(j, val);
    }
    int value=-1;
    int currE=arr[0];
    for(int i:arr){
        if(hm.get(i)>value){
            value=hm.get(i);
            currE=i;
        }
    }
    return currE;
}
```

`

Hope this helps someone. Also, do let me know in case my approach is wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> seen=new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
         
        int key=arr[i];
        // int count=0;
        if(seen.containsKey(key)) {
             int count=seen.get(key);
             count++;
             seen.put(arr[i], seen.get(key)+1);
        }
        else {
            seen.put(key,1);
        }
    }
        int max_count = 0, res = -1;
         
        for(Entry<Integer, Integer> val : seen.entrySet())
        {
            if (max_count < val.getValue())
            {
                res = val.getKey();
                max_count = val.getValue();
            }
        }
        return res;
 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MaimumFrequencyNumber {

```
public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){ 
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : arr) {
        hm.put(i, hm.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
    }
    int max = 0, ans = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (hm.get(i) > max) {
            max = hm.get(i);
            ans = i;
        }

    }
    return ans;
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
     
    int arr[] = {1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1}; 
     
    System.out.println(maxFrequencyNumber(arr));
}
```

}

Comment: The question is tagged C++ and your answered doesn't provide an explanation for why OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).